# Do not open RStudio internal browser after knitting

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I'm working on a presentation in RStudio using rmarkdown and [revealjs template](https://github.com/jjallaire/revealjs). Since it's a work in progress, I often knit the .Rmd file to see the changes.

The problem is, each time I press "Knit" button (or use a hotkey), an internal browser window pops up. I don't need it, really, because 1) it displays the presentation incorrectly and 2) I already have the .html file open in my system browser and I simply refresh the page.

Is there any way to suppress the default RStudio behaviour?

Ideally, I'd love to be able to knit and see the result in the system browser (with focus on it) in as few keypresses as possible. Right now, my solution is to `source(render.R)`, which contains a call like

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(revealjs)
render("main.Rmd", 
       revealjs_presentation(theme="black", highlight="zenburn"), 
       encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Better than nothing, but still a bit tedious (set focus from editing to console, source, refresh page -- 3 actions). Any suggestions?

For an MWE, open [New File] -- [R Markdown...] and hit "Knit HTML" or Ctrl+Shift+K.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- just added this to RStudio (check dailies.rstudio.com, build 637 or later); go to Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Display -> Show R Markdown output in -> Do not show output.

Comment: @Jonathan That's wonderful! Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Jonathan I've checked the latest build, works fine. Feel free to post that info as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RStudio keeps moving this feature around.  Johnathan's answer was good for the prior version of RStudio that I was using.  You could find it starting with **Tools > Global Options** and then if you are on 0.99.x, here:

[image]

I'm currently on 1.0.44 and now it's here:

[image]

In all fairness to RStudio, I think creating a new **R Markdown** option section and putting it here makes good sense.

Answer (score 4):

To add a litte bit to the answer of Michael (on how to disable the internal window):

I am using only the following script by sourcing it **to render the file and open the resulting html file in the browser** in one step:

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(revealjs)

file.name <- "introduction"
path.to.file <- "vignettes/"

rmarkdown::render(file.path(path.to.file, paste0(file.name, ".Rmd")),
       revealjs_presentation(theme="default", highlight="default"),
       encoding = "UTF-8")

browseURL( file.path(path.to.file, paste0(file.name, ".html")))
```

Note: This script does also work within a package project of RStudio.