# Rmarkdown and rstudio - reveal js print pdf.css error

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, reveal.js

After I have created a revealjs-presentation in my Rstudio-project, i proceed to open it. This works fine except that I get an error in my browser (Chrome) that pdf.css doesn't exist. Which it doesn't, because the presentation is looking for it in a sub-folder in my project directory. Now, I can add pdf.css according to the path that fails and the presentation works...until I re-run it and the added directory is deleted (I guess the knit process delete the aformentioned sub-folder?)

This is a minor problem but there seems to be something buggy going on here, anyone got any idea what I could do (besides re-installing everything)?

Example at the bottom

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: revealjs::revealjs_presentation
---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Code and Output

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

And this is the folder-tree that's missing (relpath from a given Rstudio project):

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

/TestRevealJs_files/reveal.js-3.3.0/css/print/paper.css
```

Where TestRevealJs is the name of the project.

Comment: Could you add a minimum example here please?

Comment: @RYoda Absolutely - updated the question

Comment: I have created a project, added your example as a new file and pressed the knit button. I do not get an error (just an empty window where I have to click on the "open in browser" button to see the presentation in my browser. At which step I have just described do you get the error "pdf.css does not exist"? Have you installed the package `revealj` (sorry, stupid question, but maybe a reason)?

Comment: What happens if you render the presentation with [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40946740/4468078)?

Comment: Thx @RYoda - I realise again that I'm a bit unclear, sorry about that. I do get the same result as you. 

When I open the presentation in my browser and check the developer tab or try to use the print pdf functionality I get the error - the presentation doesn't find the css file. I can't understand why it's looking for it in the project directory instead of in revealjs own folder (by default).

Comment: Perhaps this: `output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    self_contained: true` (don't forget the line break and indention after each colon, I cannot add formatting in here)

Comment: @RYoda no that didn't work, but setting it to false did work in this example!

Comment: `yes` seems to be the default. So all your problems are solved now?

Comment: @RYoda - no, setting it to false on my own script doesn't work out of the box. But since the testscript works it should just be a matter of time - so if you like to post it as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Thx, I have no need to gather reputation points. But perhaps you could modify your example here if the problem is reproducible so that the community can help you. BTW I had similar problems with revelJS within the vignette folder of an R package that I developed. Moving the R markdown slides into a new RStudio project did work then for whatever reason I did not investigate then. I did use the `revealjs` package without any manual side-by installation of reveal.JS