# rmarkdown::run directly displayed in the web browser?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I try to run a Rmd file (rmarkdown::run, because some shiny code) from R studio directly on the web browser and I cannot find the way.

I tried this solution: [Do not open RStudio internal browser after knitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697945/do-not-open-rstudio-internal-browser-after-knitting?rq=1)

but I don't know why it does not work for me. In any case, I was looking for a more "universal" solution, like an option of the function "run". When I look at the help, I can clearly see that: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.8/topics/run

> Unlike render, run does not render the document to a file on disk. In
>   most cases a Web browser will be started automatically to view the
>   document; see launch.browser in the runApp documentation for details.

so I tried:

```
rmarkdown::run("TCD.CleanR.Rmd", launch.browser = TRUE)

Error in rmarkdown::run("TCD.CleanR.Rmd", launch.browser = TRUE) : 
  argument inutilisé (launch.browser = TRUE)
```

(sorry for the french :D: meaning unused argument)

I don't understand why it does not work ???

Does someone has an idea?

Thanks a lot in advance  :)

Cha

Answer (score 5):

It means that the argument provided does not match any of the arguments used by the function.

`launch.browser` is not an argument of `rmarkdown::run()`, it is actually an argument of `shiny::runApp()`. It can be passed through `rmarkdown::run()` by using `shiny_args` like so:

`rmarkdown::run("TCD.CleanR.Rmd", shiny_args = list(launch.browser = TRUE))`

Comment: Ohhhhh niiice I did not understand that part :D !! Thanks a lot Jake! Super efficient :) Have a good sunday !