# Can I suppress output after knitting Rmd?

Tags: r-markdown

I want to 'Knit with Parameters' in Rmarkdown, but suppress output. Specifically, I'm knitting to powerpoint, but I do not want it to open when knitting is finished. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not open RStudio internal browser after knitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697945/do-not-open-rstudio-internal-browser-after-knitting)

Comment: @manro yes this is a working solution. Thanks!